# How can I filter "this year before today" in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am considering whether to add a column called ‘this_year_before_today’ to my date table. The purpose of this column would be to identify whether a date falls within the current year up to today.

Here’s the formula I would be using for the calculated column:

```
this_year_before_today = IF(YEAR([date]) = YEAR(TODAY()) && [Date] <= TODAY(), TRUE(), FALSE())
```

Until now, I’ve been relying on two filters to visualize data for this date period:

1. Relative date “is this year”: This filter restricts the visual to the current year, including dates after today.
2. Relative date “is in the last year": This filter restricts the visual to dates before today.

However, I find both solutions somewhat cumbersome. Is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

I can use either filters for each visual, create a column in my date table, or insert filtering in DAX measures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create two columns in your `date` table:

- `YearOffset`
- `DayOffset`.

Then add two filters:

```
YearOffset = 0

DayOffset < 0
```

I use both of those fields a lot in various reports

Answer (score 0):

I would create the column in the date table. It's preferable to putting multiple filters on visuals/pages when you can use one column to do that for you. You could also use offsets if you don't have them in your date table.

```
Day Offset = 
DATEDIFF(TODAY(),'Date Table'[Date],DAY)
```

With offsets, negatives are in the past, and positives are in the future. Offsets don't solve exactly your request, but they are very handy for time intelligence and should be in any date table.

[image]